# 160MHz Ambient Office Noise?

Tags: rf, emc

I've got a shielded tent in our office and I see one ambient element I don't have a good explanation for.

We see some ambient noise at 700MHz - 800MHz which I guess is cell-band noise.

But there is one persistent source of noise at 160MHz, that is also ambient and consistently present.  Across 30MHz to 700MHz all other ambient noise is attenuated by the tent.

What could that be source of noise be, is it RF?

I'm actually thinking maybe it is noise from the Rigol spectrum analyzer?  (Is 160MHz an FPGA?).

Comment: Get yourself a directional (horn) antenna and try to find the source. Switch off other equipment and see if that eliminates the noise. Terminate (with 50 ohms) the input of the SA, then the noise should be much less. There are so many possibilities that it is impossible to say where the RF signals come from. If you want an RF noise free environment, go sit in a Faraday cage.

Comment: If you have an A in your office, do you have any other RF test equipment? Is the SA the instrument you're using to measure the ambient noise?

Comment: @ThePhoton -- Yes, the SA is the instrument measuring the ambient noise.  If I had another one sitting, I could do a sanity check.  I need to get some longer cables and maybe move the SA around.  I'm just wondering if the SA (plus a whole bunch of preamps I have) maybe is measuring it's own internal noise.  It's weird though because the 160MHz phantom seems to periodically transmit, it doesn't seem like an actual transmitting somewhere.  And it's a darn strong transmitter if it is!

Comment: Remember If the SA is the source, it could be getting in to the internal signal path through some fault path or internal leakage and not through the antenna.

Comment: @ThePhoton -- that's kind of what I'm thinking it is, but the duty cycle of the interference seems like it's an actual intentional transmitter!

Comment: Disconnect the antenna, see if it goes away? (Bimpelrekkie already suggested this, I guess)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie -- I'm trying to build a tabletop Faraday cage. ;)

Comment: Couldn't it be someone's smartphone processor clock running on low power mode? If you keep it in your pocket, it will always be somewhat close and the noise should be persistent.

Comment: Try demodulating it to audio both with a BFO and as narrowband FM.  If he SA won't do it an RTL-SDR will if strong enough.  Can you sign out the SA to take home for the weekend?  Rigol doesn't tend to be price-of-a-new-car.  Or even drop by on the weekend when fewer are in your office and nearby..

Comment: Also, show us what it looks like in both plausible-channel-width frequency domain and (assuming your SA will do it) power-over-time.

Comment: @ChrisStratton -- I own the office, I can run around and find the offender at leisure!... Audio is an interesting idea!  I need an RTL-SDR for that.  I just was monkeying around and opened up the tent to measure somethings, and that 160MHz signal flared up. This ambient is present ALL THE TIME.  So it's definitely RF, it's not the SA.  I'm actually getting peeved, my Aaronia Bicolog I got I don't think has enough gain for the EMC measurements in lower MHz I want to make, and I've got this bastard of an ambient right in the range I'm debugging!  I own a $1000 antenna brick at this point...

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be too hard to find the source, move the antenna closer and farther away from potential radiators of EMI. Or shut each source off and see if it is the offending source (I don't have a tent, I was in a lab with some noise from 70-700MHz affecting our instrumentation only once or twice a month, we never found the source, it might have been external).

All commercial devices should be FCC certified (or European equivalent) then that means that it is acceptable. If you have one that is not certified then that could be a good source.

Many FPGA's and microprocessors have clocks in the 50-500MHz range (some even above that) so it isn't unreasonable that there is RF noise in this frequency range.

Comment: I'll go move the antenna around.  I pulled the SA, like 3 feet away and didn't see change!  Good grief.  I turned off my office lights too just cause.

Comment: Oh and if the source is outside the office, or long distance, you probably won't see a large change by moving the antenna. If it is a noise source that is beyond acceptable limits  and causing interference (and probably not lawful), contacting a government agency to get it turned off might be a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, I moved the antenna around and the source appears to be outside the immediate office (or it's the SA or pre-amp, but the duty cycle makes me think it's an actual transmitter.)

Comment: Then you start looking at who owns the radio band, and if it's acceptable

Answer (score 1):

In the US that band is mostly maritime mobile and similar. There may be some beacons. Partial spectrum allocation chart from [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/United_States_Frequency_Allocations_Chart_2016_-_The_Radio_Spectrum.pdf).

[image]

I was tracking down interference one time and used the demodulated output of the SA to confirm that it was a local radio station transmitter.

Comment: I remember when we got our first 160MHz PC in the office.  My boss at the time was an amateur radio operator and remarked that the new PC was a radio transmitter that could do math.

Comment: @JRE I was also thinking that; in modern PCs, 160MHz could be a memory or bus frequency...